# Does Paralellism for a loop keep the order of execution for statements outside the loop

Tags: c#, foreach, task-parallel-library

**Question:** In code snippet given below, will a parallel call to the loop still maintain the order of methods before and after the loop?

In other words, Method1 will first execute, then Method2, and then the parallel loop; once the parallel looping is done, only then Method3 followed by Method4 will be called.

```
Method1();
Method2();             
// Parallel loop
Parallel.ForEach(customers, customer => UpdateCustomerInfo(customer));
Method3();
Method4();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an implicit **wait** in the implementation of ForEach.  The method won't return until all of the parallel tasks have completed, so you are guaranteed that every task will be completed before Method3() is called.

Comment: Will the methods before the loop also execute in a sequence? Just wanted to make sure that methods outside execute in a sequence.

Comment: Yes, it's also guaranteed that Method2() returns before any of the tasks in ForEach() are called, so as written, everything executes in order.  However, if Method2() spawns a thread that does some other things, that thread is not synchronous with any of this unless you specifically use a semaphor.

Comment: Ok. Great Explanation. Get it now. Thanks.